# Fresh Install of Mountain Lion on MacBook Pro Retina that upgraded via a voucher

Tags: macos, install

I want to do a fresh install of Mountain Lion. I bought my MackBook Pro before Mountain Lion was out. Later I got my free download voucher and used it to upgrade. Now I want to do a fresh install, but I'm unsure how to download Mountain Lion again without paying for it.

I tried redeeming the code again in the App store, but I get an error saying this code has already been used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Mountain Lion will be available under your Purchases list. Go to `Store -> Purchases` and you'll see it there with an option to download.

Comment: Came here to say this.  The vouchers basically act as gift cards, only they are for a specific download.  Because of this anything downloaded via a voucher will typically be treated the same as any other purchase.